# For some reason when i hit the add button it adds 4 cardviews and when i long click on the cardview nothing happens

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When i hit the add button inside the Adapter class it adds 4 cardviews to the mainactivity layout and when i try to delete nothing happens and instead it adds another 4 cardviews

I tried everything nothing seem to be solving my problem

Here's my Adapter class:

```
package com.example.itask;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = "TaskAdapter";

    ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context context;

    public TaskAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    interface DeleteTask {
        void onDeletingTask(int bookId);
    }
    public DeleteTask deleteTask;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.task_list_item_rec_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");
        holder.name.setText(tasks.get(position).getName());
        holder.date.setText(tasks.get(position).getDate());
        holder.card.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Deleting task")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this task?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                try {
                                    deleteTask = (DeleteTask) context;
                                    deleteTask.onDeletingTask(tasks.get(position).getId());
                                }catch (ClassCastException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tasks.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name;
        private TextView date;
        private CardView card;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskDate);
            card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
        }
    }

    public void setTasks(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here's my MainActivity

```
package com.example.itask;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddTaskDialog.AddNewTask, TaskAdapter.DeleteTask {

    private Button buttonAddTask;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ArrayList<Task> allTasks;
    private TaskAdapter adapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonAddTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddTask);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        adapter = new TaskAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        allTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
        dataAsyncTask.execute();


        buttonAddTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddTaskDialog dialog = new AddTaskDialog();
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "add new task");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletingTask(int bookId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDeletingTask: trying to delete this task with id "+bookId);
        try {
            dataBaseHelper.delete(database, bookId);
            DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
            dataAsyncTask.execute();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class DataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Task>>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            database = dataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Task> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                cursor = database.query("tasks", null,null,null,null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                        Task task = new Task();
                        for (int j=0; j<cursor.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            switch (cursor.getColumnName(j)) {
                                case "_id":
                                    task.setId(cursor.getInt(j));
                                case "name":
                                    task.setName(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                case "date":
                                    task.setDate(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                case "notes":
                                    task.setNotes(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            allTasks.add(task);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return allTasks;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
            super.onPostExecute(tasks);
            if (tasks == null || tasks.isEmpty()) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonAddTask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonAddTask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            adapter.setTasks(tasks);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddingTask(Task task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAddingTask: new book: "+task.toString());
        try {
            dataBaseHelper.insert(database, task);
            DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
            dataAsyncTask.execute();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
            database.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my dialog class:

```
package com.example.itask;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddTaskDialog.AddNewTask, TaskAdapter.DeleteTask {

    private Button buttonAddTask;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ArrayList<Task> allTasks;
    private TaskAdapter adapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonAddTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddTask);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        adapter = new TaskAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        allTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
        dataAsyncTask.execute();


        buttonAddTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddTaskDialog dialog = new AddTaskDialog();
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "add new task");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletingTask(int bookId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDeletingTask: trying to delete this task with id "+bookId);
        try {
            dataBaseHelper.delete(database, bookId);
            DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
            dataAsyncTask.execute();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class DataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Task>>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            database = dataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Task> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                cursor = database.query("tasks", null,null,null,null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                        Task task = new Task();
                        for (int j=0; j<cursor.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            switch (cursor.getColumnName(j)) {
                                case "_id":
                                    task.setId(cursor.getInt(j));
                                case "name":
                                    task.setName(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                case "date":
                                    task.setDate(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                case "notes":
                                    task.setNotes(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            allTasks.add(task);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return allTasks;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
            super.onPostExecute(tasks);
            if (tasks == null || tasks.isEmpty()) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonAddTask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonAddTask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            adapter.setTasks(tasks);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddingTask(Task task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAddingTask: new book: "+task.toString());
        try {
            dataBaseHelper.insert(database, task);
            DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
            dataAsyncTask.execute();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
            database.close();
        }
    }
}
```

my database helper class:

```
package com.example.itask;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddTaskDialog.AddNewTask, TaskAdapter.DeleteTask {

    private Button buttonAddTask;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ArrayList<Task> allTasks;
    private TaskAdapter adapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonAddTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddTask);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        adapter = new TaskAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        allTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
        dataAsyncTask.execute();


        buttonAddTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddTaskDialog dialog = new AddTaskDialog();
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "add new task");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletingTask(int bookId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDeletingTask: trying to delete this task with id "+bookId);
        try {
            dataBaseHelper.delete(database, bookId);
            DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
            dataAsyncTask.execute();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class DataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Task>>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            database = dataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Task> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                cursor = database.query("tasks", null,null,null,null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                        Task task = new Task();
                        for (int j=0; j<cursor.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            switch (cursor.getColumnName(j)) {
                                case "_id":
                                    task.setId(cursor.getInt(j));
                                case "name":
                                    task.setName(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                case "date":
                                    task.setDate(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                case "notes":
                                    task.setNotes(cursor.getString(j));
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            allTasks.add(task);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return allTasks;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
            super.onPostExecute(tasks);
            if (tasks == null || tasks.isEmpty()) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonAddTask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonAddTask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            adapter.setTasks(tasks);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddingTask(Task task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAddingTask: new book: "+task.toString());
        try {
            dataBaseHelper.insert(database, task);
            DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
            dataAsyncTask.execute();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
            database.close();
        }
    }
}
```